# Is there a way to get the timezone information for all current timezones

Tags: delphi, winapi, timezone

I am currently working on a project where I want to collect all the timezone info for all current timezones.

The `WinApi.Windows.GetTimeZoneInformation` function only returns the current timezone data. Is there a way to get a list of all timezones?

I do not need it to be 100% accurate according to https://www.iana.org/time-zones and i do not need to store it in a database. I just need to get the data for the user to pick additional timezones for reminders.

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/

Comment: I found this and decides to use it instead: https://github.com/pavkam/tzdb

Comment: The Win32 function that does this is [`EnumDynamicTimeZoneInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-enumdynamictimezoneinformation).  I'm not sure if there's a Delphi wrapper for it already or not.  The link gabr provided below looks promising, as it works with the registry data directly, which is similar to what that Win32 function does.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this as `winapi`, you can query the following registry path:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`

The key binary blob `TZI` corresponds to a `REG_TZI_FORMAT` structure which, in Delphi, looks like this:

```
uses WinApi.Windows;

REG_TZI_FORMAT = record
    Bias:           LONG;
    StandardBias:   LONG;
    DaylightBias:   LONG;

    StandardDate:   SYSTEMTIME;
    DaylightDate:   SYSTEMTIME;
end;
```

Comment: My GpTimezone unit (freeware, https://github.com/gabr42/GpDelphiUnits/blob/master/src/GpTimezone.pas) encapsulates this in class TGpRegistryTimeZones.